# css3 firefox can't get multiple animations to work

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I have a FF v52.
[MDN says, you can do multiple animations in FF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)

, but, no matter, what I try, can't get it to work. Only the last, mentioned animation name is used, when applied:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf8'>

<style type='text/css'>
@-moz-keyframes skew0 {
 0% {
  transform: skew(0deg, 0deg);
 }
 25% {
  transform: skew(90deg, 90deg);
 }
 50% {
  transform: skew(180deg, 180deg);
 }
 75% {
  transform: skew(270deg, 270deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: skew(360deg, 360deg);
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate0 {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 25% {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
 50% {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
 }
 75% {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}
div {
 border: 4px solid black;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 animation-name: skew0, rotate0;
 animation-duration: 12s, 6s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried to do it with shorthand version, also.

#### P.S.: Excerpt from the doc, that I gave a link to about showing how to do multiple animations to one property:

Setting multiple animation property values

The CSS animation longhand values can accept multiple values, separated by commas — this feature can be used when you want to apply multiple animations in a single rule, and set separate durations, iteration counts, etc. for the different animations. Let's look at some quick examples to explain the different permutations:

In this first example, we have three animation names set, but only one duration and iteration count. In this case all three animations are given the same duration and iteration count:

```
animation-name: fadeInOut, moveLeft300px, bounce;
animation-duration: 3s;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

In this second example, we have three values set on all three properties. In this case each animation is run with the corresponding values in the same position on each property, so for example fadeInOut has a duration of 2.5s and an iteration count of 2, etc.

```
animation-name: fadeInOut, moveLeft300px, bounce;
animation-duration: 2.5s, 5s, 1s;
animation-iteration-count: 2, 1, 5;
```

Comment: The 2 animations can not animate the same property (transform)

Comment: I've left a link in my question [above] to the FF documentation from Mozilla, where they state, that you can. Take a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations

Answer (score 1):

You can't animate the same property with 2 different animations, but in this case you can combine their values in one.

And do note, the property in this case is `transform` and the `skew`/`rotate` are property values.

Updated, using multiple animations, which works as described in the docs as long as they animate different properties.

*Note, I added an unprefixed @keyframes for demo purpose*

```css
div {
 border: 4px solid black;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 animation-name: skewrotate, colorme;
 animation-duration: 12s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes skewrotate {
 0% {
  transform: skew(0deg, 0deg) rotate(0deg);
 }
 25% {
  transform: skew(90deg, 90deg) rotate(90deg);
 }
 50% {
  transform: skew(180deg, 180deg) rotate(180deg);
 }
 75% {
  transform: skew(270deg, 270deg) rotate(270deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: skew(360deg, 360deg) rotate(360deg);
 }
}
@keyframes skewrotate {
 0% {
  transform: skew(0deg, 0deg) rotate(0deg);
 }
 25% {
  transform: skew(90deg, 90deg) rotate(90deg);
 }
 50% {
  transform: skew(180deg, 180deg) rotate(180deg);
 }
 75% {
  transform: skew(270deg, 270deg) rotate(270deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: skew(360deg, 360deg) rotate(360deg);
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes colorme {
 0% {
    background-color: transparent;
 }
 50% {
    background-color: red;
 }
 100% {
    background-color: transparent;
 }
}
@keyframes colorme {
 0% {
    background-color: transparent;
 }
 50% {
    background-color: red;
 }
 100% {
    background-color: transparent;
 }
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look @ the Moz Dev Doc, where they state, that you can: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations

Comment: @igoryonya Of course you can have multiple animations, but you can't animate the same property in 2 different animations at the same time

Comment: Did you read the doc, I gave the link to? It specifically says there, that you can. Since, I can't paste the excerpt in the comment, I've pasted it in the P.S. section in my question above ^^^^^. Please, read. ^^^^^

Comment: @igoryonya We have both (LGSon and me) read the docs. You can have multiple animations. You can not have both animations set the **same** property. What should happen if you have and animation changing color from red to green, and another animation changing color from yellow to blue ?

Comment: @igoryonya I updated my answer with multiple animations, and as you can see, they work if not animating the same property.

Comment: @igoryonya And do note, the property in this case is `transform` and the `skew`/`rotate` are property values